# UISwitch Older Version

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiswitch

Want to add this kind of switch to my application rather than the rounded corner one. As its not available from iOS 5.0 onwards.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Use this link of source code](https://github.com/twotoasters/TTSwitch)   for get Square Switch 
and Create with

```
TSwitch *switch = [[TTSwitch alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect){ CGPointZero, { 76.0f, 27.0f } }];
switch.trackImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"square-switch-track"];
switch.thumbOffsetY = -3.0f;
```